# Magento 2.3.4 custom module - Uncaught Error: Call to a member function setData() on boolean

Tags: magento2, php-7.2

I've got a custom Magento 2 module that is causing issues on newly created products. All of the existing ones seem to be okay. I'm running Magento 2.3.4

in my template: /app/design/frontend/MySite/MyTheme/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/attributes.phtml

```
<?php
    $_helper = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output');
    $_product = $block->getProduct()
?>

$block->getChildBlock("myblock")->setData("my_data", $_product);
echo $block->getChildHtml('myblock', false);
```

The line that reads  <kbd>$block->getChildBlock("MyBlock")->setData("my_data", $_product);</kbd>  is throwing the following error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function setData() on boolean in /var/www/mysite.com/app/design/frontend/MySite/MyTheme/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/attributes.phtml

Any idea why this would work for all products but newly added ones? The contents of the block being referenced are irrelevant at this point as it's not making it far enough to load it.

Edited to add XML (catalog_product_view.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <move element="product.attributes" destination="product.info.price" after="-"/>
        <referenceBlock name="product.attributes">
            <block class="Catalog\MyBlock\Block\Catalog\Product\Myblock" name="catalogmyblock" as="myblock" template="Catalog_MyBlock::view/myblock.phtml">
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>
        <!-- <referenceContainer name="product.info.price" remove="true"/> -->
        <referenceContainer name="product.info.addtocart" remove="true"/>

    </body>
</page>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error means that the code `$block->getChildBlock("MyBlock")` returns false.
There is no block called `MyBlock` in your layout.

The problem can have multiple causes:
 - you did not add a block that has `as="MyBlock"`.
 - you did not add a block that has `as="MyBlock"` as a child block of your current block.
 - the block is removed from another layout file or a plugin or something else that gets executed before the layout is rendered.

I think you can check all the child names of your current block like this:

```
 $block->getLayout()->getChildnames($block->getNameInLayout());
```

if your block is not in there, try making sure it is added properly.

Comment: This is definitely the issue. Do you have any idea where to start looking for what might cause one product to not load "MyBlock" while every other product page in the same category is properly loading "MyBlock". This is loading in attributes.phtml for every single other product, shouldn't it do the same for this new one?

Comment: How is "myBlock" added in the page? What is the name of the xml file where this is added and how does the block configuration look like?

Comment: I think I've added what you asked for as an edit above @Marius.

Comment: I see that in your xml there is this `as="myblock"` but you call it in the template as `MyBlock`. Make sure the values match. They are case sensitive.

Comment: I apologize, I was trying to be extra careful when translating the case. I missed the ones in my template, They are actually lowercase as in my XML. I think the part that's really confusing me is that this exact code is working on 99.9% of the products. It's just this one new product that has an issue.  If it were just a broken call, wouldn't it be broken on every product page?

Comment: not really. It depends on different settings for the product. You can check if the product has a different theme applied, or if it has custom layout xml updates.

Comment: Thanks again for all of your help. This was the solution. The product had a different template selected. I had fixed this days ago but never refreshed the cache. I refreshed the cache and it's working as intended.

Comment: Hello... and finally what was the solution? in my case I am trying to pass some data to customer additional information in account edit form. `form.additional.info` is returned when using `$block->getLayout()->getChildnames($block->getNameInLayout())`. However, `$block->getChildBlock('form.additional.info')` returns false, and `echo $block->getChildHtml('form_additional_info', false)` displays the correct HTML. I tried by using unserscores instead of dots and viceversa, but there is no way to show that block.